# Error in returning data by parsing it to Json in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I'm new to ASP.NET. I have done Json parsing when returning the data in WebAPI controller like this,
`

```
public JsonResult getResult()
        {
            string dataconfig = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Onviodb"]);
            SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(dataconfig);
            SqlCommand cmd = null;
            String sqlQuery = null;
            SqlDataReader dataReader = null;

            var list = new List<onvioAPI>();
            try
            {
                cnn.Open();
                sqlQuery = "Select * from tbl_Projects";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, cnn);
                dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    onvioAPI od = new onvioAPI();
                    //od.id = Int32.Parse(dr["ID"].ToString());
                    od.aname = Convert.ToString(dataReader["Agency Contact Name"]);
                    od.vname = Convert.ToString(dataReader["Vendor Name"]);
                    od.pcity = Convert.ToString(dataReader["Project City"]);
                    od.pstate = Convert.ToString(dataReader["Project State"]);
                    od.vcity = Convert.ToString(dataReader["Vendor City"]);
                    list.Add(od);

                }

                cnn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Can not open connection ! " + ex);
            }

            return Json(list,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

`

But there is an error showing like 
`The best overloaded method match for Json(List,JsonSerializerSettings) has some invalid aruguments`.
What should I do ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened because there are two `JsonResult` types: one from `System.Web.Mvc` namespace(with `enum JsonRequestBehavior`) and one from `System.Web.Http.Results`(`JsonResult<T>`) and I think you mixed up them. Solution is to do this:

```
using System.Web.Http;
//using System.Web.Mvc;

    public IHttpActionResult getResult() 
    {
        //your code..
        var list = new List<onvioAPI>();
        //your code..
        return Json(list);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
List<onvioAPI> list = new List<onvioAPI>();
```

This should work.